# Example of use of requestBody() JSON in Jsoup

Tags: json, jsoup

Hello i´m trying to parse a web with a requestPayload as data, im trying using data but i failed, i dont know if i doing correctly, and i dont know how to use requestBody().

Can heplme someone with a example of use of requestBody()

My code devolve a 415 error:

```
Response responsePostLogin = Jsoup
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0") //connect and read time
            .cookies(loginPageResponse.cookies())
            .followRedirects(true)
            .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .referrer("URL/es/")
            //:authority:URL
            //.header("authority", "URL")
            //.header("accept", "Content-Type")
            //.header("charset", "UTF-8")
            //.header("accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01")
            //.header("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
            //.header("Connection", "keep-alive, Transfer-Encoding")

            //.header("Accept", "Content-Type")
            //.header("Content-Type", "text/plain,application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

            .data("email","myemail)
            .data("password","mypass")
            // connect and read time out
            .timeout(10 * 1000)


            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();
```

If i discomment

```
.header("Accept", "Content-Type")
.header("Content-Type", "text/plain,application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

I have a 400 error. I don´t know what i must to do.

When i inspect the web i need:

Request URL: url

Request Method:POST

Status Code:201

Remote Address:X.XX.XX.XX:XX

Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Respose headers.**

content-encoding:gzip

content-language:en-US

content-length:1067

content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8

date:XXXX

expires:XXX

pragma:no-cache

set-cookie:  "cookies"

status:201

vary:Accept-Encoding

x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN

**Request Headers**

:authority| Url

:method|POST

:path|/RestOfURL

:scheme|https

accept|*/*

accept-encoding|gzip, deflate, br

accept-language|es-ES,es;q=0.8

content-length|68

content-type|application/json

cookie| "cookies"

origin| URL

referer| URL/es/

user-agent|Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36

**Query String Parameters**

languageId:-5

appId:1

**Request Payload**

{email: "myemail", password: "mypass"}

email:"myemail"

password:"mypass"

*Thanks, and sorry about my english it´s my firs consult*

Comment: Fire your favorite browser, enable the developers tools to see the headers it exchanges by visiting your target url. You'll quickly know the correct headers to send when using Jsoup.